# How can I restrict the IP address to access Gitlab web page?

Tags: gitlab

My gitlab is using docker container to build.
Today I receive the gitlab email that my account is locked due to an excessive amount of unsuccessful sign in attempts.
I believe that my gitlab account is hacking by hacker.
Can I set up a white list to display the gitlab login page?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can setting by nginx.
https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html
you can create folder and file in: `"/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf"` 
then update gitlab.rb:
nginx['custom_nginx_config'] = `"include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;"`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to set an allowlist by your cloud service like AWS.